# Need to be able to login and browse websites get htmlDocument from Website

Tags: c#, html, authentication, html-agility-pack, pack

I need to be able to login to a website. Preferably be able to save the login credentials in cookies. After that I should be able to browse to website while at anytime be able to get the htmldocument.

I am already using Html Agility Pack to parse websites. And would be satisfied with if I just could load the HtmlDocument using the login credentials, but haven't been able to so far. I have tried with both HtmlWeb and by using an HttpWebRequest.

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myemail", "mypassword");
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

// There are various options, set as needed
htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags=true;

HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
WebProxy prox = new WebProxy(url);
try{
    htmlDoc = hw.Load(url, "POST", prox, new NetworkCredential("myEMAIL", "mYPAssword"));
}catch(HtmlWebException ex){
    Console.WriteLine("htmlParser.cs " + ex.Message);
}
```

It just won't login. There are no error messages.

```
try{
   var temp = new Uri(url);
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(temp);
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myUsername", "myPassword");
    request.CookieContainer = myContainer;
    request.PreAuthenticate = true;

    request.Method = "POST";
    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
         {
             htmlDoc.Load(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8"));
         }
    }
```

}

Comment: "I have tried" Then why didn't you show your code? Please add that to your question and explain what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this task I would highly recommend [**Selenium**](https://youtu.be/mluLgBywW0Y?list=PL6tu16kXT9PqKSouJUV6sRVgmcKs-VCqo). Instead of just hoping your code will work, Selenium will show exactly what's going on in a regular browser like **Firefox** or a headless browser like [**PhantomJS**](http://phantomjs.org/).

Selenium is also a great tool for [**web scraping**](http://thiagomarzagao.com/2013/11/12/webscraping-with-selenium-part-1/) if you want to do that.

Comment: I have looked into Selenium. Is there a way for me to get the entire HtmlDocument from Selenium as a string. If this is so. then i am definitely going to use Selenium

Comment: I tried everything! I even tried to install Windows on a virtual machine in order to make the WebBrowser class. Then I tried WatiN. And finally I gave in and tried Selenium. You were right. This is the optimal solution. After installing it took my less than 5 minutes to produce some working code. I am missing one thing though. I am not interested in showing/knowing what exactly is going on in the browser. Is there anyway to hide it?

Comment: Actually yes, you can use PhantomJS instead, like I shown you in my answer. Instead of declaring a variable like `var browser = new FirefoxDriver();` you can declare it like this: `var browser = new PhantomJSDriver();`. It will work without changing anything else. Although if you mean without opening any windows, I'm out of luck on this one.

Comment: Ya. I want to keep everything in the background as much as possible. But Selenium is indeed fantastic. I am only struggling with getting PhantomJS to run in wine. But that is a nonissue at this point.

Comment: Hi @Kent , I found a completely headless WebDriver called **SimpleBrowser**. However it doesn't support JavaScript, so that might be an issue. Check out this: http://deanhume.com/home/blogpost/selenium-webdriver---using-a-headless-browser-in--net/69